# My understanding on Fubini thereom

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Fubini thm says:
[image]

but In fact the **only** way to compute the multiple integral is term by term

so we **always** use the following:
[image]

Is there any **exception**?

Comment: Um, I mean Fubini's theorem is extremely useful, but there is not only one way to compute integrals in life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fubini's Theorem doesn't say that. It simply says that if $f\ge0$ or $f\in L^{1}(d\mu)$ then this is one option. This is not the only way to compute the double integral. However, it is a rather useful tool. Usually to apply Fubini's Theorem one first makes use of Tonelli's Theorem to check the $L^{1}$ condition for Fubini to hold (your version of Fubini builds Tonelli into it). As noted before it is not always required to use Fubini to evaluate the double integral. For example when integrating characteristic functions it may make the integration far more complicated than it has to be. Other times symmetry can be used to compute the integral but having to apply Fubini's Theorem would make the computation difficult. For example integrate $f(x,y)=x$ over a domain, $A$, such that if $x\in A$ then $-x\in A$. Many times the change of variables theorem can be more useful in simplifying an integral like changing the integral of a radially symmetric function in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to an integral in polar coordinates.

Comment: Oh I see.Given a function f.apply tonelli to |f|.reduce it to iterated integral .if the integral is finite,then apply fubini to f,iterated integrate again.correct?

Comment: Yes that is the way the two theorems are usually applied together.